# Rails: PaperClip alongside Sidekiq and postprocessing of image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip, sidekiq, minimagick

I am using the `Paperclip` gem to allow my users to upload an avatar (which is uploaded/hosted on `S3`) but am having issues when it comes to server performance. It seems to take forever to upload the photo and I am thinking it's because it runs through all of the conversion metrics before redirecting the user back to their profile on a successful upload.

Here is my PaperClip settings:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, PAPERCLIP_OPTIONS.merge(
    :default_url => "//s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/media/avatar-placeholder.gif",
    :styles => {
      :"58x58"   => "35x35^",
      :"150x150" => "56x56^",
      :"184x185" => "165x110^",
      :"259x259" => "259x259^"
    },
    :convert_options => {
      :"58x58"   => "-background transparent -auto-orient -gravity center -extent 58x58",
      :"150x150" => "-background transparent -auto-orient -gravity center -extent 150x150",
      :"184x185" => "-background transparent -auto-orient -gravity center -extent 184x185",
      :"259x259" => "-background transparent -auto-orient -gravity center -extent 259x259"
    }
  )
```

Is there anyway to utilize `Sidekiq` to offload the convert options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a gem that you can use.  https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/

As described, you can config paperclip with DJ, Resque and Sidekiq, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found this gem shortly after posting my question lol